# boost::beast ws_.async_handshake breaks when synchorneous function works

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-beast

I've built an app that connects to bitmex through boost::beast. 
The synchronous call works fine using the code provided at:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync-ssl/websocket_client_sync_ssl.cpp

however the code that does the same thing asynchronously at:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp

always breaks (cores) exactly when the websocket handshake is performed:

```
on_ssl_handshake(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    if(ec)
       return ;//fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    **ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/realtime",
        std::bind(
            &session::on_handshake,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));**
}
```

The /realtime is the target that the data should be coming from on the server side.

Comment: Needs more information. Can you check the versions that you built against vs those found at runtime. Run with asan/ubsan or valgrind etc. Also, you don't show the actual code.

Comment: Where's the strand?

Comment: my understanding is the strand is used only if multiple threadfs are making the asynchroneous calls, which is not the case. I need to clarify that the crash happens only because of our delayed logging, not when the handshake is performed. The bottom line is I am not sure how to receive callbacks from the server and process then accordingly. Should I expect the data to show up in the on_write method? It seems that one the io.run the example code wants to close the socket. I take it if I don't close it the updates will call the on_write callback

Comment: no strand in my code

Comment: code built with boost_1_67

Comment: Was this resolved?